# stanford parser or an alternative to it in dotnet

Tags: .net, nlp, stanford-nlp

i'm working on a Q&A project in the dotnet framework and i need something that do the NLP processes like , Part of speech tagging , and generating parse trees

i know Stanford parser but am a little bit confused about finding an interface to it in C# 
i searched for a good alternative and i found :

1- http://nlpdotnet.com/Services/Introduction.aspx   (but it doesn't provide parse trees )

i wonder if there are some good alternatives as well

Answer (score 6):

Good news, Stanford Parser(was recompiled for .NET, using IKVM.NET) is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/sergey-tihon/fsharp-stanford-nlp-samples). Description about how it was done you can find [here](http://sergeytihon.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/nlp-stanford-parser-with-f-net/). The same assembly can be used not only from F#. It can be used from any .NET language, for example C#.

Comment: Stanford Parser is available on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Stanford.NLP.Parser/) now, as well as some [other Stanford products](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=stanford).

Answer (score 3):

One choice that might work is Proxem Antelope: http://www.proxem.com/Default.aspx?tabid=119 . This incorporates the Stanford Parser. Another choice would be SharpNLP http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/ , which ports OpenNLP to C#. There is also a port of MSTParser to C#: https://github.com/rasoolims/MSTParserCSharp/ . Other choices include the C# program invoking a Java parser in a separate process or using a tool like IKVM that lets you run Java programs (a Java VM) inside a .NET application: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Main_Page . I have no experience on whether it works for the Stanford Parser, though. [Update: It does! See Sergey's answer.]